# Why python skips printing a certain index in a list?

Tags: python, forecasting

I am trying calculate a forecast and it uses a list of a values from index 11 to 27 the zeros are needed for adjusting indexes. So as I calculate the forecasted values the numbers are a little lower than I expected. I look for any problem with code and I can't find anything that would make it go wrong. I decide to print the values of a list used in the forecast and it doesn't print index # 16 for some reason so I think that is what is causing the problem. The code:

```
import numpy as np



# I(t) Equations Number (1 & 2)
def I(t, K, Q, Lambda, v):  
    return (K / (1 + Q * np.exp(-Lambda * t)) ** (1 / v))

    
# N(t) Equations Number (3 & 4)
def N(t, K, Q, Lambda, v):
    if t <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return I(t, K, Q, Lambda, v) - I(t - 1, K, Q, Lambda, v)



C = [0, 7, 16, 23, 33, 42, 49, 55, 59, 63, 68, 72, 77, 81, 87, 90, 95, 100, 106, 112, 115, 119, 123, 127, 129, 132, 136, 140, 143, 145, 149, 152, 156, 160, 163, 166, 170, 174, 179, 183, 187, 192, 197, 201, 206, 210, 215, 218, 222, 227, 231, 234, 238, 243, 247, 252, 257, 260, 265, 271, 277, 282, 287, 291, 296, 301, 305, 311, 316, 322, 328, 333, 340, 344, 350, 355, 362, 368, 373, 379, 386]



a = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.46858931479187e-05, 1.6206955838810076e-18, 8.985307651607066e-19, 7.003624779270066e-19, 1.1709296887835827e-19, 4.3331201413108664e-19, 1.0737658462711186e-19, 8.496193547355917e-20, 1.3898073202217e-19, 1.8233410168260659e-19, 2.15624909023167e-19, 2.475963618209771e-19, 3.8252420297863168e-19, 4.242115816032489e-19, 7.589290882438663e-19, 4.8984182123788976e-18, 6.215727674683693e-18]

    

print(len(a))


Days = len(C) - 1


Taomin = 11
Taomax = 27


K = 28136042.234956194
Q = 1
Lambda = 0.02871447779455746
v = 2


Number_of_days_to_Forecast = 6


Forecasted_Days = range(Days + 1, Days + Number_of_days_to_Forecast + 1)

Last_Predicted_Day = Days + Number_of_days_to_Forecast



for i in range(Taomax + 1):
    print(a[i], ' ', i)




# List of Forecasted 
Forecast = []


# Forecast Calculation
for t in Forecasted_Days:
    x = 0
    for k in range(1, Last_Predicted_Day + 1):
        if k <= t:
            for j in range(Taomin, Taomax + 1):
                x += a[j] * N(k - j, K, Q, Lambda, v)
    Forecast.append(x)
    

print(Forecast)
```

The output:

```
28
0.0   0
0.0   1
0.0   2
0.0   3
0.0   4
0.0   5
0.0   6
0.0   7
0.0   8
0.0   9
0.0   10
5.46858931479187e-05   11
1.6206955838810076e-18   12
8.985307651607066e-19   13
7.003624779270066e-19   14
1.1709296887835827e-19   15
1.0737658462711186e-19   17
8.496193547355917e-20   18
1.3898073202217e-19   19
1.8233410168260659e-19   20
2.15624909023167e-19   21
2.475963618209771e-19   22
3.8252420297863168e-19   23
4.242115816032489e-19   24
7.589290882438663e-19   25
4.8984182123788976e-18   26
6.215727674683693e-18   27
[356.90236573940047, 359.3246781887185, 361.69013308570345, 363.99977702653774, 366.25465185585256, 368.45579386232725]
```

As you can see it doesn't print a[16] and I don't know if it even takes it into account when doing the forecast. The strange thing about it was that like an hour before index # 16 started to go missing I tried some adjustments as changing lists and so on hoping it would work the problem was the same just a different index wouldn't appear.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into a console and it prints `a[16]` as well with a value of `4.33312014131086e-19`

Comment: I tried it again on VS Code shows the same thing no a[16]. I tried it on an online python website and it worked. Could it be something with the editor?

Comment: Can't say, all you seem to be doing is to be printing values in `a`. Can you try printing `a` itself before / after the for loop?

Comment: Printing the whole list at once is another problem I had most of the time it prints the list with no problem at all. A few of the times I tried to print the list it doesn't print all elements only till index # 20 or so.

Answer (score 1):

In my python 3.8.10 with numpy 1.22.3, the scripts run correctly if you change the print

```
(a_values[i], ' ', i)
```

by

```
print(a[i], ' ', i)
```

I dont know why are you calling the object in a list in such way, but the usual call is the way i've write before.

Have a nice day!

The output:

```
    28
0.0   0
0.0   1
0.0   2
0.0   3
0.0   4
0.0   5
0.0   6
0.0   7
0.0   8
0.0   9
0.0   10
5.46858931479187e-05   11
1.6206955838810076e-18   12
8.985307651607066e-19   13
7.003624779270066e-19   14
1.1709296887835827e-19   15
4.3331201413108664e-19   16
1.0737658462711186e-19   17
8.496193547355917e-20   18
1.3898073202217e-19   19
1.8233410168260659e-19   20
2.15624909023167e-19   21
2.475963618209771e-19   22
3.8252420297863168e-19   23
4.242115816032489e-19   24
7.589290882438663e-19   25
4.8984182123788976e-18   26
6.215727674683693e-18   27
[356.90236573940047, 359.3246781887185, 361.69013308570345, 363.99977702653774, 366.25465185585256, 368.45579386232725]
```

Comment: Must have been when I changed list names. If you don't mind could show me the forecasted output.

Comment: hey bencomo, welcome to stackoverflow! please use crtl K to format your codeblocks, it is much easier to read

Comment: Oh! I didn't know this option, and thanks for the welcome!!